# define-values macros in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to write a define-values macros in Clojure?
Racket language provides such a thing like define-values form which acts in this way

```
(define -values '(a b c) (1 2 3))
```

Where a, b, c are global variables now.
How can I do it in Clojure?

```clj
(defmacro defvar [x y]                                                     
     `(let [a# ~x                                                              
            b# ~y]                                                             
        (def b# a#)))                                                          
                                                                               
                                                                               
  (println (defvar 'a 2))


=> #'user/b__2__auto__

;;;It binds the value to  auto generated symbol
```

Answer (score 4):

`define-values` doesn't make any sense in Clojure. It makes sense in Racket because `values` lets one expression evaluate to multiple values. In Clojure, an expression always evaluates to exactly one value: there's no `values` to extract into definitions.

Of course, you can write a macro `def-several-things` such that

```
(def-several-things [x y] [1 2])
```

expands to

```
(do (def x 1)
    (def y 2))
```

but this is less readable, not more, so nobody does it.

Comment: I just want to know how to do that

Comment: @user324885 https://i.imgur.com/ccTqs7N.png 

```(defmacro def-several-things [symbols values]
  `(do ~@(map (fn [s v] (list 'def s v)) symbols values)))

(macroexpand
 '(def-several-things [x y] [1 2]))
```

Comment: @user2609980 If you have an answer to the question, please post it as an Answer, not as a comment on my answer.

Comment: @amalloy this is an answer to the comment. @user324885 asked how to write out your suggestion of using a macro `def-several-things`.

Answer (score 1):

Note you can also use [`clojure.template/do-template`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.template/do-template):

```clj
(clojure.template/do-template
  [name val]
  (def name val) a 1 b 2 c 3)
```

this will give you vars `a b c` with vals `1 2 3`.

Expansion:

```clj
(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(do-template [name v] (def name v) a 1 b 2 c 3))
;; => (do (def a 1) (def b 2) (def c 3))
```